# XCode Continuous Integration Missing AppIcon in Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I've got a continuous integration server setup with XCode 5 that was running automated schemes rather well until yesterday when I switched my project settings to using the asset catalog. Following this change, all builds submitted to my continuous integration server would fail with a single error:

```
error: /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/AppIcons/appicon72@2x.png: No such file or directory
```

My last resort seems to be just to create that folder on the remote server, but perhaps there is some other way to solve this?

- The AppIcons directory doesn't exist in that location on the server.

Comment: Is the 72px retina image (114x114px) added to your asset catalog?

Comment: I believe so. Viewable [here](http://i.imgur.com/c8Ujy2X.png)

Comment: Try adding that file with exact this name to your project and see if it helps. It does not matter that it is in the asset catalog too.

Comment: IS that the `Cache` folder I should add or the `AppIcons` folder. Should I add it to the top level directory of my project?

Comment: Add it anywhere in your project. It does not matter if it is in the top folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the icon file to my folder I was presented with a somewhat different error viewable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W39op.png) close analysis revealed errors in the log to the effect of a failing copy in the build process see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGl7F.png). Creating the AppIcon folder in the Data/BotRuns/Cache/ folder with the appropriate icons did the trick.

The real issue here was an erroneous relative paths in my xcodeproj file for a resource. Ammending the path fixed the issue for everyone.